# Can We Make Blender's Island Packing More Space-Efficient When Unwrapping?

Tags: modeling, uv

Here is the object I am working on. I have finished marking seams so I want to proceed to texturing, but this is the result when unwrapping:

[image: A Blender screenshot, with a 3D model of a SMG on the left, and its unwrapped UV layout on the left. The UV layout has the letters "A" and "B" marking empty portions of the UV layout.]

That's quite a bit of empty space! It seems like blender draws an invisible box around each island and sorts them that way, but this leads to large areas of empty space, especially when dealing with complex islands. Is there any way to automatically pack them closer together without lots of manual placement afterwards?

Comment: Blender's UV packing uses convex hulls of shapes afaik. There may be plugons somewhere that do this better, I'm not sure.

Comment: It does not even use convex hulls, it uses the island bounding box. There are several addons that use alternative packing methods, such as UVPackmaster

Answer (score 2):

The "UVPackmaster" addon do what you asked for. It's good for automatic optimization of the shells in the UV space.

Here is the link: https://glukoz.gumroad.com/l/uvpackmaster3

Comment: Is there anything close to UVPackmaster which is free "as in beer"?

Comment: As I know, MagicUV (https://www.blendernation.com/2018/02/18/magic-uv-v5-0-released/) is an addon that embeds several tools for uv editing (among which uv packing). I've never used it, but you can try if the results are better than the basic Blender's uv pack tool. An alternative is to use a different software only to unwrap your model, like Roadkill (http://www.pullin-shapes.co.uk/page6.htm). It's a basic software, you can only unwrap the model, but the packing is automatically done.

Answer (score 0):

A free alternative addon for optimizing UV layouts is [UV Packer](https://www.uv-packer.com/blender/). Be aware that this addon is limited to Windows and Linux only.

[image]
(Disclosure: the screenshot is from the UV Packer website itself and might be showing a best case scenario)